# LWJGL/Slick2D - How to delete texture?

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm writing a game project. I have got a lot of textures and animation, so I have to delete some textures. For example, I don't want to use textures from Main Menu when I play.

I use simple:

```
Texture texture;
texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));
```

And for drawing:

```
texture.bind();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
 glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0,0);
 glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(1,0);
 glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(1,1);
 glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0,1);
glEnd();
```

For example, in Main Menu I load some textures, and I want to play, so I go to the Play screen, which shouldn't use Main Menu textures. Those textures from the Main Menu screen are still in memory. I've got some of them and it is about 30Mb RAM - I don't want them, so I should delete them. So now, I want ask, is there any way to delete those textures? I read about it much, but I still don't have an answer.

Comment: For everyone, you should just use texture.release(); The most easiest thing every, how much time lost.